# When will the database connection be closed in prestashop 1.6.1.3 version?

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

**When will  the database connection be closed in prestashop 1.6.1.3 after a db instance is created by $db  = Db::getInstance();**

Do I need to close the database connection manually by writing any code db close function?
Or the db class in prestashop will handle this?
Actually when will be the PrestaShop db connection will be closed after a db object is created by  $db  = Db::getInstance();?

See below code which is a simple php file in my root directory of prestashop to update one of my tables and this page is called every one minute by cron job task ,here I am not closing the connection anywhere ,do we need  to close it ?

```
$CheckStatusSql = "select * from  ticket_status where item_id='$ItemID' and ticket_series='$TicketSeries' and status='BOOKED'  ";   
$db        = Db::getInstance();
$result    = $db->executeS($CheckStatusSql, false);     
$ChangeStatus ='';
while ($row = $db->nextRow($result)) {
    $status    = $row['status'];
    $booked_on = $row['booked_on'];
    $ticket_no = $row['ticket_no'];              
    $to_time   = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));// Time Now 
    $from_time = strtotime($booked_on); //Booked Time
    $time_diff_minutes=round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);                
    if($time_diff_minutes>$checkMinutes){
    $ChangeStatus=$ChangeStatus."Booked ticket no: '".$ticket_no."' exceeds 30 Minutes and its now about ".$time_diff_minutes." minutes, status changed to AVAILABLE<br><br\>";
    $updateSql = "UPDATE ticket_status SET status = 'AVAILABLE', booked_on = NULL  WHERE item_id='$ItemID' and ticket_series='$TicketSeries' and status='BOOKED'  and ticket_no='$ticket_no'"; 
    $bookResult = $db->executeS($updateSql, false);
    }
}
```

That is I am just including the config file (require 'config/config.inc.php';) and creating a db object and then executing my query as shown below :

```
require 'config/config.inc.php';
$checkMinutes       = 30;//  In minutes
$checkTimeInSeconds = $checkMinutes*60;
$sql                = 'SELECT * FROM ps_ticket WHERE status=5';
$db                 = Db::getInstance();
$result             = $db->executeS($sql, false);   
$i=1;
while ($row = $db->nextRow($result)) {
    $time    = strtotime($row['hold_on']);
    $curtime = time();
    if(($curtime-$time) > $checkTimeInSeconds) { ///3600 seconds    
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'lopp_ticket`
        SET
        `id_customer` = 0,
        `hold_on`=0,
        `status` = 1
        WHERE  `ticket_id` = '.$row['ticket_id'];
        if(Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)) {
            echo $row['ticket_id'].'&nbsp;Updated'.'<br>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $row['ticket_no'].'No'.'<br>';
    }
    $i++;

}
```

So here do I need to close the db connection anywhere in the above code or PrestaShop will handle itself?
Because the server admin is saying too many database sessions are been opened by our code ,
Also Is there anyway to check from where too many db sessions are open/active always ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know i never have closed a DB connection in Prestashop.

There [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/database/) also does not explicitly state to close each DB request.
Looking into there source code they also never run a close command after a DB connection.

Looking into the classes\db\DbMySQLi.php class we can find the function below.

```
/**
 * Destroys the database connection link.
 *
 * @see DbCore::disconnect()
 */
public function disconnect()
{
    @$this->link->close();
}
```

Then we will look into classes\db\Db.php where we find that the function `$this->disconnect()` is called. So its safe to say they will close all there DB connections automatically.

```
/**
 * Closes connection to database.
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    if ($this->link) {
        $this->disconnect();
    }
}
```